# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget + ViewPagerAdapter

Tags: android, out-of-memory

Helllo,

I got this problem with ViewPagerAdapter. On various phones it sometimes crashes and sometimes not and can't put my finger on the cause. I even made largeHeap for API>14 and still got this on. Anyone know what's going on?

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(BitmapFactory.java)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:563)
       at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:439)
       at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
       at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1981)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:601)
       at android.widget.ImageView.resolveUri(ImageView.java:501)
       at android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(ImageView.java:280)
       at com.example.package.ViewPagerAdapter.instantiateItem(ViewPagerAdapter.java:85)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:832)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1048)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Comment: Sounds like the picture's just too big - have you tried resizing them? You don't need a huge picture when it's going to be scaled down for the small screen anyway.

Comment: someone have a lot of pictures on sd card and you store all loaded bitmaps in memory and not releasing them

Comment: I have pictures the same resolution as 1920x1080 so I thought the quality would be the best. To what resoultion should I scale this to make it smaller? And would that work this out?
@nickes - how can I release bitmap from ViewPagerAdapter when it's made so next and previous bitmap is loaded automatically?

Comment: 1920x1080 it is 8mb per picture or 25mb per 3 pictures. And older phones are limited to 16mb of application memory. No wonder it crashes.

Comment: So, no matter how compressed it is - the only thing that matters is resolution?